# How to select random objects in eCognition?

Tags: accuracy, ecognition

I classified a Landsat image in eCognition and now I want to select random objects so that I can compare their class to ground-truth data and perform the accuracy assessment. How can I do this in eCognition?

Comment: which version of ecognition you are with (9.x etc, developer,architect etc)?

Comment: @msi_g I am using eCognition Developer version 8

Comment: It is better to export ecognition classified objects into vector and load field verified points into arcmap/qgis afterward generate a comparison matrix in excel(easiest way) then calculate Producer's/Consumer's Accuracy etc..